# past perfect or past simple with work

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-past-perfect

is there any difference between these sentences?

> I had worked hard so I needed a break
>
> I worked hard so I needed a break

Comment: Both are valid, but the first (Past Perfect) is probably better in most contexts - in particular because the conjunction ***so*** explicitly calls attention to the fact that the first clause (working hard) ***preceded*** the second (needing a break). And Perfect forms are *specifically* favoured when the sequence of two actions is significant, AND the later one occurs at "narrative reference time". Where narrative reference time is ***now*** (time of utterance) for Present Perfect, or ***then*** (the time of needing a break) in your Past Perfect context.

Comment: I can't say the second is absolutely wrong, but I prefer the first.

Comment: You can't *unilaterally* endorse one over the other. In general, the Perfect form is more likely for most contexts, but there can certainly be contexts where Simple Past is actually ***necessary***. For example, if ***I worked hard*** refers to my ***habitual*** action in the past - *The other workers avoided over-exerting themselves so they could work steadily all day long without stopping, but **I worked hard, so I needed a break***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you, you've pretty much cleared my confusion I really appreciate it. This is the best explanation I've seen so far

Comment: But if "so "the conjunction  tells the reader that the first clause preceded the second isn't it a repetition to use past perfect because we already know it due to the use of so